# cordova build error after add cordova image picker plugin

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I am developing an app using Cordova.
Everything is fine but after add image-picker plugin,
build Cordova action give me this error:

[image: build Cordova screenshot]

Can anyone help me solve this error ???????

Answer (score 0):

It happens sometimes.Make a copy of the Project as Backup Before try the following.

**Solution 1:**
Remove and add the particular plugin

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-image-picker
```

**Solution 2:**
Remove and Add Platforms.

```
cordova platform remove android
cordova platform add android
```

**Solution 3:** tTry to Update Cordova CLI and platforms to the latest one

Check the Official Guide Lines [here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.1.0/guide/cli/index.html#updating-cordova)